# Share Types between WCF Service References and still auto-generate INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wcf, inotifypropertychanged

I have two WCF services that need to share types between each other (i.e The output of service1 needs to be the input to service2).  I am familiar with the option in Visual Studio to "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies" and this would make my scenario work.

That is, until I mention that I am missing out on the auto-generated code that svcutil.exe (via Visual Studio) would typically give me.  I'm missing the auto-implementing of INotifyPropertyChanged on all properties, making IEnumerable objects into ObservableCollections, etc.

Is there a way to reuse types between two services but also get all of that auto-generated goodness, most specifically the INotifyPropertyChanged?  I do not want to write all that code by hand within the currently very small classes which reside on the server side.

Using .Net 4.0.

Comment: In what way is EF relevant? Are you using EF entities in your service contracts?

Comment: Check out NotifyPropertyWeaver. http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/

Comment: @JohnSaunders Noted, EF is likely irrelevant in this situation since those entities are not being sent through WCF.

Comment: @cadrell0 - The NotifyPropertyWeaver works great. I love magic!

Comment: @cadrell0 If you want to put this as an actual answer I think its worthy of an 'Accept Answer'

Answer (score 0):

You could put the message types in their own assembly and then reference this assembly from client and service. The autogenerated code is useful, when the service is not in your hands.